# iPod touch and .pdf files

Tags: ipod-touch

Can iPod touch store .pdf files and open them without any Internet connection? My friend just bought one and he could not explore a feature like that yet. He says that iTunes does not allow transferring of .pdf files to iPod touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found the solution:The programs name is **goodreader**. You can download files in the formats like .doc,.docx,ppt,pptx,pdf,txt,html and view them offline.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way to transfer files of any kind to an iPod touch/iPhone through syncing. You can e-mail, or download from the web, or contain one within an application, but I don't believe you can sync a pdf.

Comment: I don't have an iPod touch or iPhone to test with, but can you not connect it as a named device, like you can with the older iPods?  I copy all sorts of files to and from my ancient 3G iPod all the time in both Windows Explorer and Mac Finder.  Of course you still can't open them...

Comment: I've not tried connecting my iPod touch to my Windows PC, but certainly on my Mac the device is only "mounted" within iTunes, not in the general file system, like the classic iPods. I seem to recall iPod shuffles do the same.